# How can Mass Spectrometry have high sensitivity but average reproducibility?

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, reproducible-research, chemometrics

I am reading up on mass spec from this link: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/training/online/courses/metabolomics-introduction/designing-a-metabolomics-study/comparison-of-nmr-and-ms/
They state:

> The two most common techniques used in data acquisition are nuclear magnetic resonance and >mass spectrometry. Table 1 shows some of the key differences between the two techniques.
>
> |  | Nuclear magnetic resonance (NMR) | Mass spectrometry (MS) |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Sensitivity | Low | High |
> | Reproducibility | Very high | Average |

I suppose I can understand how a test can have low sensitivity, but high reproducibility - it gets the same positive samples correct/incorrect each time, with most being incorrect.  But how can a test have high sensitivity but average reproducibility?  Does this mean if I run the test once, it gets most positive samples correct, but if I run the test again it gets different samples correct - it does not seem possible to do both in my estimation but I would like to hear an explanation from someone with a better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In analytical chemistry, *sensitivity* is used with two distinct meanings:

- The [sensitivity of a test that yields disease vs. not-this-disease output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) is the fraction of test samples (cases, units) correctly identified as diseased by the test among all those test samples (cases, units) that were truly diseased.
- The [sensitivity of an instrument (signal)](https://sisu.ut.ee/lcms_method_validation/34-sensitivity) is the slope of the instrument response curve, i.e. change of instrument response/signal as function of the change in measured quantity (typically analyte concentration).

The post refers to the instrument signal: mass spectrometers yield high (difference in) counts i.e. signal already for very small (difference in) concentrations of the target analyte.
But this signal is not very stable (reproducibility). In analytical chemistry terminology, the reproducibility in the post would already be [intermediate reproducibility (intra-lab/inter-session)](https://sisu.ut.ee/lcms_method_validation/41-precision-trueness-accuracy) if not [repeatability](https://sisu.ut.ee/lcms_method_validation/41-precision-trueness-accuracy).

If the mass spec says "target analyte is there" it's there. But if another sample (truly) has twice the concentration of the target analyte, you cannot rely very well on the signal of that sample being twice as large as the first (in mass spec, ionization efficiency can depend a lot on the [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(chemical_analysis)), i.e. the "surrounding stuff" of the analyte).
Thus, signal-to-noise ratio is not that great for mass spec.